# MVP with handle long run task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, mvp

I am writing software that applying MVP(Model, View, Presenter) on Winform using .net C#. I got a trouble with designing Presenter class that handle long run tasks (take time to calculate and response). 
I researched on internet and know how to use TPL Task or async/await on .net 4.5. But with doing that, I need to applying it for each action from view.

Now, I want to design Presenter class that receive actions from view, automatically executes them in other threads (like use Task, ThreadPool,...) and update result back to GUI without any cross-thread exceptions.

Example: I want to control Robot, I have RobotView, RobotPresenter, and RobotController that handle all actions to send to Rotbot devive
At RobotView Class, I handle an action HomeRobot, call presenter.

```
 Private Sub btnHome_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHome.Click
        AVPLib.Log.guiLogger.Info("Enter btnHome_Click")
        Dim strMessageText As String = String.Empty
        Try
            strMessageText = AVPLib.ContainerData.GetMessageText("HomeButtonCenterRobotCassettes")
            If Utils.ShowAVPMessageBox(strMessageText, HOME_TM, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.OK Then
                **_presenter.HomeRobot()**
                AVPLib.ContainerData.LogAlarmEvent(AVPLib.ContainerData.TypeUser, AVPLib.ContainerData.LogSource.AVPMainScreen,
                                                             "[Main Screen]" & " Home Click")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            AVPLib.Log.avpLogger.Error(ex.ToString())
        End Try
        AVPLib.Log.guiLogger.Info("Leave btnHome_Click")
    End Sub
```

At Presenter: I call RobotController(Model) to execute Home action that take long time (send command to device, wait for return response)

```
  Public Function HomeRobot() As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        HEventLoggerWrapper.Debug("Enter HomeRobot.")

        Try
            _robotView.EnableDisableAllButton(False)
            Dim taskResult As Task(Of Boolean) = Task.Run(Function() _robotController.SafetyHomeRobot())
            taskResult.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(Sub() result = taskResult.Result)

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogParameterUtility.LogErrorParameter(HEventLoggerWrapper.Logger,
                                                   [GetType]().Name,
                                                   "HomeRobot",
                                                   MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex)
        End Try

        HEventLoggerWrapper.Debug("Leave HomeRobot. Result = " & result)
        Return result
    End Function
```

So, it worked but I need to apply Task.Run/GetAwaiter... for all of actions (ArmUp, ArmDown, Extend, Retract,...). I also do the same thing for other presenters (other devices). It is very waste time.

I want to design a way that, every function from view call Presenter.DoSomeThing will automatically run on another thread because they are long run task.

Hope someone could help

Regards,

Comment: Why don't you show us some code of what you've tried so far? Would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: What is your concrete problem? What you say is correct, but what does not work? My assumption so far: You haven't really gotten how to use TPL and async/await. Hint: Presenter methods must be declared as `... async Task DoActionX()`, Model methods must be declared as *async* `Task` or `Task<T>`. You might need to use `await Model.DoActionX().ConfigureAwait(...)` depening on your situation (see this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more information).

Comment: I updated the code for clear meaning

Comment: You obviously did not understand the whole concept of TPL and async/await. I'll try to build an example quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. It helps me to use TPL and async/await in the right way. However, it has not solved my concern. Actually, we have 2 groups to build a project. 1 group is creating view classes. So, they do not care about async/await. They only know where they call a function at presenter to do. Ex: Click button HomeRobot, will call presenter.HomeRobot, click button ArmExtend, will call presenter.ArmExtend. With my group work on presenter class, we need to design Presenter class that put these actions to another thread to do (because they are long run tasks).

Comment: And I am stuck with design like that

Comment: In summary, View does not care about it is a long run task or not. View just knows to call presenter.DoSomeAction. Presenter need to put all actions from view calling to other thread to do for preventing blocking GUI due to long run task. Hope you can give me an example with design like this

Comment: I have request like this because our team want to change old project to MVP. Model and View were built and we want to keep them as before(do not want to change traditional functions to async functions). So, we just write presenter class that receive request from view, call model execute in another thread, receive result and update back to view.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches for this issue. The most elegant and probably the "best practice" (please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) is to make the handler method itself *async void*. Here be said: This is the **only** case where you should use `async void`. Else always use `async Task`!

If you don't want to make your handler async, you could also use `Task.Factory.StartNew(PresenterActionMethod).ContinueWith(AnotherHandler);` but this is a relatively bad approach. You would need another handler method which would be called from another thread and thus had to invoke on the UI thread if you change any UI controls. Using `Task.Wait(...)` wouldn't work since it blocks the UI thread.

This just as little side information. But using it like this would work perfectly fine.

```
///=================================================================================================
/// <summary>   Handler in your View class. </summary>
///
/// <param name="sender">   Source of the event. </param>
/// <param name="e">        Event information. </param>
///=================================================================================================
public async void ViewEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set some UI stuff
    // Here we need to use ConfigureAwait(true) since we will interact with the UI after this method call
    await PresenterActionMethod().ConfigureAwait(true);

    // Set some UI stuff again
}

///=================================================================================================
/// <summary>
///     This method is inside your Presenter class and is expected to return once the long
///     running method of your Model is finished.
/// </summary>
///
/// <returns>   A Task. </returns>
///=================================================================================================
public async Task PresenterActionMethod()
{
    // Do stuff
    await ModelLongRunningTaskMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // Do other stuff
}

///=================================================================================================
/// <summary>
///     This method is inside your Model class and is expected to be a long-running method.
/// </summary>
///
/// <returns>   A Task. </returns>
///=================================================================================================
public async Task ModelLongRunningTaskMethod()
{
    // ... do your stuff here
    // You should use ConfigureAwait(false) here since you don't need the captured context
    // this improves performance and reduces the risk of deadlocks
    await Task.Delay(6000).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```